# How many groups of order $815,409=3^2\times 7^2\times 43^2$ are there?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

I aborted GAP after some hours. I wanted to approve my conjecture that $gnu(n)<n$
for all cubefree numbers $n>1$, where $gnu(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$, but the case $p^2\times q^2\times r^2$ seems to be already complicated.

> Does anyone know whether $gnu(815,409)<815,409$ holds, or even the value of $gnu(815,409)$ ?

Comment: Which GAP command have you tried - ConstructAllGroups from GrpConst package, or NumberCFGroups from cubefree package?

Comment: Can I use NumberCFGroups at once, or do I need to do something before ? I used ConstructAllGroups.

Comment: Also, I suggest to look at getting account at [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) where you can leave some calculations running for a longer time (free accounts are available, you will get more power with paid accounts starting from IIRC US$ 7 per month). Also, there is [MEDICIS](http://www.medicis.polytechnique.fr/compte_us.php) though I haven't used it for a while, but may be worth trying.

Comment: I prefer offline-solutions. If they do not work, it is OK. I am not a friend of programs accessing to the internet, and I avoid paid services in the internet in principle. It seems too dangerous for me. I have great interest in group theory at the moment, but it is after all limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: $415$.

In more details: for cube-free orders, one should use the [Cubefree](http://users.monash.edu.au/~heikod/cubefree.html) package by Heiko Dietrich. It takes about a minute to get the answer, which is $415$, using the beta-version of GAP 4.8 (namely, GAP 4.8.1) with most recent GrpConst and Cubefree:

```
gap> LoadPackage("cubefree");
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Loading  GrpConst 2.5 (Constructing the Groups of a Given Order)
by Hans Ulrich Besche and
   Bettina Eick (http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick).
Homepage: http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick/so.html
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

   - Construction Algorithm for Cubefree Groups, 1.11 - 
   ------- Heiko Dietrich, H.Dietrich@tu-bs.de -------- 
Loading Cubefree 1.15 ... 
true
gap> NumberCFGroups(815409);
415
gap> time;
61078
```

Comment: The same number also arises with `grpconst` with the patches I recently submitted.

Comment: If you will try GAP 4.7, you will get an error - this will be fixed in GAP 4.8 (that's why I was using its beta-version).

Comment: @ahulpke great, good to have this cross-check!

Comment: Would it be sufficient to add some files to my current GAP-version ?

Comment: No - you need to download beta-release or clone the repository from GitHub (https://github.com/gap-system/gap) and then add packages manually. Or wait till the public GAP 4.8 release.

Comment: bad news indeed :(

Comment: Why bad news? Is installing a new gap version such a hurdle? If so, *that* is bad news to us, and I'd love to hear why exactly it is such a problem, so that perhaps we can make it easier for you in the future. Any replies most welcome (also fell free to email me, or email the GAP support list.) Thank you!

Comment: I've looked in the mail archive (in particular, [this](https://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/gap/2015-December/000368.html)) and figured out that you may try to get cubefree 1.15 from http://users.monash.edu.au/~heikod/cubefree.html and replace the one from your current GAP installation. This will be newer than 1.13 redistributed with GAP and may work with GAP 4.7.9 (but of course, YMMV).

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I downloaded a windows-version of cubefree and copied the directory in the GAP-directory. But the NumberCFGroups command does not work.

Comment: I also downloaded and copied polycyclic, but the command still does not work.

Comment: And I embedded also irredsol, without success.

Comment: Are you sure that you followed installation instructions from cubefree's README? See e.g. http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/cubefree/README.cubefree but is is also include in the archive that you've downloaded.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov after 2 minutes my pc returns me this:
`gap> NumberCFGroups(815409);
Error, Record: '<rec>.orbit' must have an assigned value in
  pnt := S.orbit[1]; called from 
StabChainStrong( S, GeneratorsOfGroup( G ), options ); called from
StabChainOp( G, rec(
    base := [ 1 .. LargestMovedPoint( G ) ] ) ) called from
MinimalStabChain( G ) called from
GeneratorsSmallest( b ) called from
Set( C1 ) called from
...  at line 2 of *stdin*
you can 'return;' after assigning a value
brk>`

Comment: I've solved it using Cubefree 1.15 instead of 1.13.

Comment: See my comments above - they explain that you need to use newer Cubefree

Comment: Great, @AngelBlasco - thanks for confirming that it works! So Peter need not to upgrade to GAP 4.8 beta to get this working.

Comment: @Alexander Konovalov I unzipped the cubefree1.15tar-files, but I cannot load the package. GAP returns "fail".

Comment: @Peter you wrote "I downloaded a windows-version of cubefree and copied the directory in the GAP-directory." - that rings a bell, do you mean that you unpacked it `gap4r7`? For it should be in `gap4r7/pkg` replacing the older cubefree that sits there.

Comment: I guess there is no -win.zip archive of cubefree 1.15 at the moment

Comment: Unfortunately, the tar-file does not work. Do you have any idea what I can do ?

Comment: Does the archive unpacks correctly - can you read e.g. pdf manual from there?

Comment: No, there is only one file.

Comment: ??? which program are you using to unpack it? Can't see the button to switch to chat :( - that would be more convenient

Comment: 7z1514 , a program to unzip tar-files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34400/discussion-between-alexander-konovalov-and-peter).