# How many groups of order $2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 11^2\cdot 13^2$ exist?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

The calculation of the number of groups of order

$$2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 11^2$$

(result $81883$) takes already two hours with GAP. So, the calculation of
the number of groups of order

$$2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 11^2\cdot 13^2$$

probably is already very time-consuming.

Any ideas how I can get the number more efficiently ?

Comment: Hint: Sylow's Theorems are likely very helpful here, because the powers of each prime are less than $3$, there are only a few possibilities for the sylow $p$-subgroups (There are, up to isomorphism, only 2 groups of order $p^2$ for each primes $p$, namely the cyclic group of that order, and the elementary abelian group of that order).

Comment: Speaking to GAP commands, have you tried cube free algorithm? Mentioned in comments here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607419/how-many-groups-of-order-815-409-32-times-72-times-432-are-there?rq=1

Comment: Yes, this package needed $2$ hours to determine the $81883$ groups.

Comment: Computation group theory is hard. I have used GAP for computing large automorphism groups for research into the Automorphism Series conjecture (Simon Thomas, 1960), finite relative of Automorphism Tower problem. I ran into perform issues, even after learning a lot about how to improve its efficiency (I managed to construct some autgroups of order $>10^{30}$ though!)

Comment: Have you actually tried the calculation for 81883? Two hours is not a lot of time, and if you want to get these counts you should be prepared to devote weeks of computer time.

Comment: I reproduced `NumberCFGroups(5336100)=81883` in 83 minutes.